# Search string in multiple files to write lines into one file

Tags: string, search, batch-file

I'm relatively new in trying things out in the command prompt.
In the end I'd like to write a batch file that can do the following things.

Look for files whose name does not contain "foo" or "bar" with the extension "txt" 
in the current directory, including all sub directories, 
and search for lines starting with "create file" or "create table," 
so that all corresponding matching lines would be put into a new file named "y" 
In the form of name of file in which the line was found, location of the file, and the actual line containing the string.

Comment: Have a look at `findstr /?` please.

Comment: What operating system?  Windows? Linux? ...?

Answer (score 1):

Start by looking at these commands.

#### Commands

`for`,
`find`,
`findstr`

Use the `/?` argument for help.

#### Batch References

[SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/),
[DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/),
[Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php),
[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390.aspx)